# Change value of String without if statement

Tags: java, arrays, string, performance, if-statement

I need to transform a few values of a String array (String []) to Int and i would like to do it avoiding unnecesary code if possible.

Here is an example of what i do.

I read a line of a CSV file Example:

```
11;;000000000000000;2023-01-01;000;600;021;3008577;*********C;OPTIONAL;1005698;555;25;43;59999;0.00;0.00;0.00;S
;********E;000000000000000;2023-01-01;000;600;021;3008577;*********C;OPTIONAL;1005698;555;25;43;59999;0.00;0.00;0.00;N
```

And I do this (reading of the file is not important so let´s skip that):

```
     for (String fileSingleLine: contentFile) {
                String[] line = fileSingleLine.split(";");
                finalContent.append(customDTO.setLineValues(line).append("/n");
     }
```

Inside of my evaluator I need to transform the first value that can be a number or and empty String to int with a simple

```
Integer.valueOf(line[0])
```

This obviously throws a NumberFormatException so i would have to check first if the string isEmpty and do this:

```
int values;

if(line[O].isEmpty()) {
        values = 0;
} else {
        values = Integer.valueOf(line[0]);
}
```

Is there any way to do this avoiding ternary operators and if else statement?

---

PD: After doing a few benchmarks with files with over 100K lines i have around a 30% improvement using the concat option instead of the if-else one. The only change in the code that i applied between both tries is the following one:

```
//        if (StringUtils.isBlank(line[0])) {
//            contenido.append(Integer.valueOf("0")); 
//        } else {
//            contenido.append(Integer.valueOf(line[0]));
//        }
        
        contenido.append(Integer.valueOf("0".concat(line[0]).trim()));
```

filewise the order between first objects been empties and having value is random to avoid the predictor algorithm.

Comment: "Is there any way to do this avoiding ternary operators and if else statement?" - what's the purpose of trying to avoid the most obvious approach? I'd personally use the conditional operator, as a simple one-liner: `int values = line[0].isEmpty() ? 0 : Integer.valueOf(line[0]);`. I don't see why you'd expect or need it to be any simpler than that.

Comment: Why is it so important to avoid them? What are you looking for?

Comment: I am looking for performance, and also for basic curiosity. the file can be quite long and it´s imposible to predict if the string will be empty or not so it will cause quite a big delay in the processing of the file. if i have to check if all the important variables are empty or not first, it will make a mess in the complexity of the program

Comment: Also, there are quite a few options for example working with objects with Objects.toString(Objects, default) and Element.getOrDefault operations and i would like to know if there is something similar to Strings, more for the sake of knowledge in this case than for performance issues

Comment: @Grismak maybe you have heard the phrase ["premature optimization is the root of all evil"](https://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization). Don't do that.

Comment: yeah, i know, and usually this would not be a problem but on the other side, i am also curious about if this is possible in java and there is a way to do this, the easy way is more than clear,but i struggle to think that this is the best way to do such a simple operation

Comment: If the number **cannot be negative** you could simply prefix the string with a "0". `int values = Integer.valueOf("0" + line[0]);`. If the value can be negative this will result in an invalid string (for example `"0-123"`), which will throw an exception.

Comment: The compiler may be optimizing most of these variations anyway. Only benchmarking could tell it. But in any case I don't think these changes are going to increase the speed in any measurable way. Better profile your application and look for real bottlenecks.

Comment: I understand your point aled, but i think the effort is worth, even if the benchmarking showed a neligible improvement, just the knowledge about which option is faster in this sort of basic operation makes the effort worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways i can think of to do it without if-else or ternary. But i wouldn't recommend anyone using them. They are just to feed the curiosity.

#### 1. Using `try-catch`

```java
int values;
try {
    values = Integer.parseInt(line[0]);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    values = 0;
}
System.out.println(values);
```

#### 2. String concat

```java
int values = Integer.parseInt(line[0]+"0")/10;
System.out.println(values);
```

The `0` is appended at last so that negative numbers don't cause any problem.

Comment: Really interesting, i will bench and try a version of the second one with concat i think it can be faster

Comment: @Grismak be careful though. The second approach will create `NumberFormatException` if the number is greater than `214748364` or less than `-214748364`. Because adding `0` after that means it would no longer fit in an `int`

Comment: yeah, this values are quite specific if i got anegative a null or a bigger number is ok to throw an exception (the file is bad) so it is a corner case thing but the point of view is much appreciated

Comment: int value = Integer.valueOf("0".concat(line[0]).trim());